# Recommended way of plugin configuration with "tasks.withType(Foo) {...}" or "foo {...}"?

Tags: gradle

I'm learning Gradle and am confused to see two styles of how plugins are configured, depending on which tutorial/book I read:

```
checkstyle {
    ignoreFailures = true
}

tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

The first one looks cleaner but the second one would also apply to custom tasks that inherit from "Checkstyle". I suspect that the latter makes it easier for the IDE to guess the type and allow proper auto completion, is that right?

Is there a general trend towards one or the other that I should follow?

Comment: If you want the task named `checkstyle`, and this task only, to be configured, you use the first one. If you want *all* the tasks of type Checkstyle to be configured, you use the second one. One is not better than the other. They just do different things.

Answer (score 0):

The two are slightly different

`checkstyle {...}` will configure a single task named "checkstyle". It will fail if a task named "checkstyle" does not exist

`tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {...}` will configure any tasks in the project of type `Checkstyle`. This could result in zero, one or multiple task instances being configured.